# PHP Getting a value from a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array from a metals exchange, and I am trying to get the AUD value from it

The JSON is below

```
{
    "GoldPrice": {
        "per": "gram",
        "date": "2013-01-23 11:51:48",
        "ARS": {
            "currencyname": "Argentine Peso",
            "bid": "268.9399"
        },
        "AUD": {
            "currencyname": "Australian Dollar",
            "bid": "51.4023"
        },
        "BRL": {
            "currencyname": "Brazilian Real",
            "bid": "110.6755"
        },
        "CAD": {
            "currencyname": "Canadian Dollar",
            "bid": "54.1633"
        },
        "CHF": {
            "currencyname": "Swiss Franc",
            "bid": "50.3933"
        },
        "CNY": {
            "currencyname": "Chinese Yuan Renminbi",
            "bid": "337.5324"
        },
        "COP": {
            "currencyname": "Colombian Peso",
            "bid": "96364.8523"
        },
        "EUR": {
            "currencyname": "Euro",
            "bid": "40.7594"
        },
        "GBP": {
            "currencyname": "British Pound",
            "bid": "34.223"
        },
        "HKD": {
            "currencyname": "Hong Kong Dollar",
            "bid": "420.5594"
        },
        "IDR": {
            "currencyname": "Indonesian Rupiah",
            "bid": "521834.3896"
        },
        "INR": {
            "currencyname": "Indian Rupee",
            "bid": "2911.3477"
        },
        "JPY": {
            "currencyname": "Japanese Yen",
            "bid": "4797.0196"
        },
        "KWD": {
            "currencyname": "Kuwaiti Dinar",
            "bid": "15.2753"
        },
        "MXN": {
            "currencyname": "Mexican Peso",
            "bid": "686.7926"
        },
        "MYR": {
            "currencyname": "Malaysian Ringgit",
            "bid": "164.9691"
        },
        "NZD": {
            "currencyname": "New Zealand Dollar",
            "bid": "64.3396"
        },
        "PEN": {
            "currencyname": "Peruvian Nuevo Sol",
            "bid": "138.6441"
        },
        "PHP": {
            "currencyname": "Philippine Peso",
            "bid": "2203.9583"
        },
        "RUB": {
            "currencyname": "Russian Rouble",
            "bid": "1637.4859"
        },
        "SEK": {
            "currencyname": "Swedish Krona",
            "bid": "354.3917"
        },
        "SGD": {
            "currencyname": "Singapore Dollar",
            "bid": "66.5474"
        },
        "TRY": {
            "currencyname": "Turkish Lira",
            "bid": "96.0565"
        },
        "USD": {
            "currencyname": "United States Dollar",
            "bid": "54.2447"
        },
        "VUV": {
            "currencyname": "Vanuatu Vatu",
            "bid": "4881.8746"
        },
        "ZAR": {
            "currencyname": "South African Rand",
            "bid": "489.4774"
        }
    }
}
```

The part I would like is

"AUD": {
                "currencyname": "Australian Dollar",
                "bid": "51.4023"
            },

I would like to get the Bid value and load it into a variable.

If someone could please assist as I have tried

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
 echo $jsonArray->GoldPrice->AUD->bid;
```

But nothing is displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You passed second parameter `true` to `json_decode` it's converted to associative array so you should call like this `echo $jsonArray['GoldPrice']['AUD']['bid'];`  OR you can remove second parameter `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code you have above, simply remove the `, true` portion of your `json_decode`.

The true flag makes the output of json_decode into an associative array, instead of leaving it as an object. Accessing using `->` traverses through an object. ([PHP Manual: json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

So really, you have two options.

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json);
echo $jsonArray->GoldPrice->AUD->bid;
```

or

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jsonArray['GoldPrice']['AUD']['bid'];
```

Personally, I generally go with the second option.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you. I always get stuck on arrays. This has helped a lot.

Comment: Thank you kind internet sir! Arrays can be really confusing, but just picture them as folders - each time you go a level deeper, you've moving into another child folder.